# Android SDK Image view floats above webview

Tags: android, sdk

all what do you add to the xml file to allow an imageview float above a webview or camera view etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#e2e1e3" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pm" 
    />

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a different Layout, such as `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2e1e3" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pm"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thats caused it to hide when put in landscape i would want the imageview to float above the webview

Comment: @M0n5terBunny, My mistake. I just made an edit to change the z order.

Comment: how would i put the image in the top left corner

Comment: @M0n5terBunny, remove the `ImageView` attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, and replace it with `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`.